# Quadratic interpolation imputation method

Tags: r

Can anyone show me how to impute missing data using quadratic interpolation. I know that the `zoo` package provide linear and cubic interpolation.

1. How about quadratic interpolation?
2. How to check whether the value imputed is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I might be completely missing the point, but I guess quadratic interpolation is rare for the following reason: two data points define a line, and four define a cubic curve. So you can interpolate using either one or two data points on either side of the gap you're interpolating. With quadratic curves, though, you need three points, which you cannot distribute evenly on both sides of the gap.

Answer (score 4):

*The high number of upvotes encourages me to turn my comment into an answer.*

Quadratic interpolation is rare for the following reason: two data points define a line, and four define a cubic curve. So you can interpolate using either one or two data points on either side of the gap you're interpolating. For the cubic case, you could also use the four degrees of freedom to match function values and slopes on both sides of the gap, which leads to cubic spline interpolation.

With quadratic curves, though, you need have three degrees of freedom. So you'd need three points to define the interpolation shape, which you cannot distribute evenly on both sides of the gap.

Possible “solutions”:

- You could do an **asymmetric** interpolation, i.e. use two data points on the left but a single point on the right of the position. The result would likely be asymmetric as well.
- You could do **piecewise** quadratic **approximation**, using more than three points to fit a quadratic curve. But with approximation the curve won't pass through your data points, so pieces won't line up properly.
- You could do a **global** quadratic **approximation** of your whole data set, but that would not be interpolation at all.
- You could use two degrees of freedom to match one data point at every end of the segment, and use the third degree to shape the curve in some symmetric way, e.g. by requiring the **slope in the middle** to be zero. But the result would likely “wobble” far more than the simple linear interpolation, so I'd consider it inferior.

I would advise none of these, but I cannot think of a better answer to your question. For each computation, you could verify whether a given implementation matches the design idea, but as all the design ideas are in my opinion flawed, that kind of correctness still won't ensure that the interpolated value actually makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

For polynomial interpolation and visualizing the resulting fit, I guess you might try something along the lines of:

```
x <- runif(100,-2,2)
y <- x**2-rnorm(100) # an approximately quadratic relation between x and y. 
plot(x,y)
quadratic.model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x**2))
int <- function(x) predict(quadratic.model,list(x=x))
plot(int,xlim=c(-2,2),col="navy",add=T)
segments(x,y,x,int(x),col="red")
```

...the 'correctness' can of course only measure distances between imputations and observations.

Comment: This is approximation, not interpolation.